# Return value of if/else recursive function incorrect but print value correct

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion, return

Trying to use recursion to solve a riemann sum.

```
def f(x):
    import math
    return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

liTotal = 0
def radExpo(start, stop, step):
    global liTotal
    x = start
    area = f(x)*step
    liTotal += area
    numOfRects = (stop - start) / step
    if start > (stop - (2 *step)):
        return liTotal
    else:
        return radExpo((start+step), stop, step)

radExpo(12, 16, 1)
```

If I change if return statement to

```
print liTotal
```

or if I call the function with

```
print radExpo
```

It works correctly but if I call/return it regularly it returns the wrong value so I can't use what is returned.

Comment: You don't actually need the else

Comment: isn't the else the recursive call back to the function?

Comment: you can only return one or the other not both on each call

Comment: I don't want both. I just want the if to return the value liTotal when it's conditional is met.

Comment: don't worry you won't get both that is  my point.

Comment: 6.848645835538622 is what is expected and returned if I print liTotal. If I use return liTotal I get 68.48645835....

Comment: No, that is not what you get. I have just run this and it correctly returned 6.84... But since you never reset liTotal, if you run it ten times you will indeed get 68.4..

Comment: Don't do `import math` inside a function - move it before the function.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a question about what is wrong with the code, I would refactor the code to remove the global reference and it will improve its reliability.  I was not able to recreate your issue where the `print liTotal` is different that `print radExpo(12,16,1)`

A modified version of your code, that removes the global variable reference looks like this:

```
def f(x):
    import math
    return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

def radExpoNew(start, stop, step):
    x = start
    area = f(x)*step
    if start <= (stop - (2 *step)):
        area += radExpoNew((start+step), stop, step)
    return area

print radExpoNew(12,16,1)  # prints 6.84864583554
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't even really think about adding the recursion to the area based on the start condition.

Answer (score 0):

Some simplifications:

```
from math import e, log

# rule #1:
# e ** (a*b) == (e ** a) ** b

# applying rule #1 twice:
# e ** (log(0.5) / 5.27 * x) == ((e ** log(0.5)) ** (1/5.27)) ** x

# rule #2:
# e ** log(k) == k

# applying rule #2:
# e ** log(0.5) == 0.5
# 0.5 ** (1/5.27) == 0.8767556206241964

# so we get:
def fn(x):
    return 10 * 0.8767556206241964 ** x
```

Then `radExpo` is essentially doing tail recursion (calling itself once at the end of the function), so we can rewrite it non-recursively:

```
def integrate(fn, start, stop, step):
    steps = int((stop - start) / step)
    return sum(
        fn(start + k*step)     # calculate x directly for each step
        for k in range(steps)  #   to prevent error accumulation
    ) * step
```

This gets rid of the global variable that was causing issues (because you did not reset it before calling the function again).

Then

```
>>> integrate(fn, 12, 16, 1)
6.848645835538626
```

and as a bonus you can integrate whatever function you like:

```
>>> from math import pi, sin
>>> integrate(sin, 0, pi, 0.001)
1.999999361387437    # pretty darn close to 2.0
```